# how to persist a spark Date type column into a DB Date column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataSet contains a Date type column, when I tried to store this dataSet to DB i'm getting :

> ERROR: column "processDate" is of type date but expression is of type character varying

which obviously telling that I'm trying to store a varchar type column in a date column, however, I'm using to_date (from *sql.function*) to convert the *processingDate* from string to Date (which works, I tried it ) 

 can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are using for date transformation?

Comment: for the transformation from String to date ? if so I'm using : data.withColumn("processDate",to_date(data("processDate")))

Comment: the processDate has the required format in order to be converted properly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your data is on the specified data format, you can also pass the format explicitly to `to_date()` function.

Sample data:

```
val somedata = Seq(
  (1, "11-11-2019"),
  (2, "11-11-2019")
).toDF("id", "processDate")

somedata.printSchema()
```

Schema for this sample data is:

```
somedata:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: integer, processDate: string]
```

You can do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date
val newDF = somedata.withColumn("processDate", to_date('processDate, "MM-dd-yyyy"))

newDF.show()
newDF.printSchema()
```

Above code will output:

```
+---+-----------+
| id|processDate|
+---+-----------+
|  1| 2019-11-11|
|  2| 2019-11-11|
+---+-----------+
```

With the following schema:

```
newDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, processDate: date]
```